# error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [LastName]: [LastName]

Tags: apex, unit-test, scheduled-apex

I wrote a scheduler class. It is working fine and test coverage also covered, but When I am deploying from sandbox to production then Got an error.

[image]

Scheduler Class:

```
global class PartnerLeadtoAccountScheduler implements Schedulable {

    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {

        map < Id, Account > mapAccount = new map < Id, Account > ();

        set < string > checkDuplicateEmail = new set < string > ();
        set < Id > updateSet = new set < Id > ();
        set < Id > conflictSet = new set < Id > ();
        set < String > emailEntry = new set < String > ();

        List < Partner_Lead__c > partnerLead = [Select id, Business_Nature__c, Company_Name__c, Contact_Number__c, Contact_Person__c, Date__c, Designation__c, Email_Address__c, Package_Plan__c, OwnerId, CP_Name_Text__c, createddate FROM Partner_Lead__c WHERE Email_Address__c != Null];
        system.debug('--partnerLead--' + partnerLead);

        List < Partner_Lead__c > partnerLead1 = [Select id, Business_Nature__c, Company_Name__c, Contact_Number__c, Contact_Person__c, Date__c, Designation__c, Email_Address__c, Package_Plan__c, OwnerId, CP_Name_Text__c, createddate FROM Partner_Lead__c WHERE Email_Address__c != Null order by createddate asc];
        Map < string, schema.RecordTypeInfo > rtName = schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName();
        Id rt = rtName.get('Lead').getRecordTypeId();

        Map < string, schema.RecordTypeInfo > rtName1 = schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName();
        Id rt1 = rtName.get('Merchant').getRecordTypeId();

        mapAccount = new Map < Id, Account > ([SELECT id, Subscription_Email__c, Channel_Partner__c, Closure_Source__c, RecordTypeId FROM Account]);
        for (account acc: mapAccount.values()) {
            checkDuplicateEmail.add(acc.Subscription_Email__c);
        }

        system.debug('mapAccount' + mapAccount);

        Map < String, Partner_Lead__c[] > assotiactedServiceByEmail = new Map < String, Partner_Lead__c[] > ();

        List < Partner_Lead__c > partnerleadToBeUpdated = new List < Partner_Lead__c > ();
        List < Account > accountList = new List < Account > ();
        List < Account > updatedAccountList = new List < Account > ();

        Map < string, Account > mapSAB = new Map < string, Account > ();
        Map < string, Account > mapUpdatedSAB = new Map < string, Account > ();
        Partner_Lead__c plead;
        for (Partner_Lead__c pl: partnerLead) {
            plead = new Partner_Lead__c(id = pl.id);
            if (!checkDuplicateEmail.contains(pl.Email_Address__c)) {

                Account acc = new Account();
                acc.LastName = pl.Contact_Person__c;
                acc.RecordTypeId = rt;
                acc.Business_Type__c = pl.Business_Nature__c;
                acc.Company_Name__c = pl.Company_Name__c;
                acc.Phone = pl.Contact_Number__c;
                acc.Designation__c = pl.Designation__c;
                acc.Subscription_Email__c = pl.Email_Address__c;
                acc.AccountSource = 'Channel Partner';
                acc.Channel_Partner__c = True;
                acc.Package_Plan__c = pl.Package_Plan__c;
                acc.CP_Name__c = pl.OwnerId;
                acc.Cp_Date__c = DateTime.valueOf(pl.createddate).Date();
                acc.CP_Name_Text__c = pl.Company_Name__c;
                // system.debug('--acc--'+acc.Id);
                //plead.Updated__c=true;
                accountList.add(acc);  

                // partnerleadToBeUpdated.add(plead); 

            }
            if (checkDuplicateEmail.contains(pl.Email_Address__c)) {

                Map < string, schema.RecordTypeInfo > rtName2 = schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName();
                Id rt2 = rtName.get('Lead').getRecordTypeId();

                Map < string, schema.RecordTypeInfo > rtName3 = schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName();
                Id rt3 = rtName.get('Merchant').getRecordTypeId();


                Account ac = [Select Id, Subscription_Email__c, RecordTypeId from Account where Subscription_Email__c = : pl.Email_Address__c Limit 1];
                system.debug('--ac--' + ac);
                system.debug('--rt3--' + rt3);
                system.debug('--rt2--' + rt2);
                updatedAccountList.add(ac);
                if (mapAccount.get(ac.Id).Closure_Source__c == 'Organic' && mapAccount.get(ac.Id).RecordTypeId == rt3) {
                    mapAccount.get(ac.Id).Channel_Partner__c = true;
                    mapAccount.get(ac.Id).Closure_Source__c = 'Channel Partner';
                    mapAccount.get(ac.Id).CP_Name__c = pl.OwnerId;
                    mapAccount.get(ac.Id).CP_Name_Text__c = pl.Company_Name__c;
                    mapAccount.get(ac.Id).Cp_Date__c = pl.Date__c;
                    mapAccount.get(ac.Id).Package_Plan__c = pl.Package_Plan__c;
                    //plead.Updated__c=true;
                    //system.debug('--plead.Updated__c--'+plead.Updated__c);
                    //mapAccount.get(ac.Id).Updated__c = true;
                    //inserFlag = false;
                    //updateFlag = true;
                    //partnerleadToBeUpdated.add(plead); 
                } else if (mapAccount.get(ac.Id).Closure_Source__c != 'Organic' && mapAccount.get(ac.Id).RecordTypeId == rt2) {
                    mapAccount.get(ac.Id).Channel_Partner__c = true;
                    mapAccount.get(ac.Id).CP_Name__c = pl.OwnerId;
                    mapAccount.get(ac.Id).CP_Name_Text__c = pl.Company_Name__c;
                    mapAccount.get(ac.Id).Package_Plan__c = pl.Package_Plan__c;
                    mapAccount.get(ac.Id).Cp_Date__c = pl.Date__c;
                    //plead.Updated__c=true;
                    //system.debug('--plead.Updated__c--'+plead.Updated__c);
                    //mapAccount.get(ac.Id).Updated__c = true;
                    //inserFlag = false;
                    //updateFlag = true;  
                    //partnerleadToBeUpdated.add(plead); 
                }
            }
        }
        List<Partner_Lead__c> pllist=new list<Partner_Lead__c>();
        if(accountList!=null){
        for (Account acc1: accountList) {
            system.debug('--acc1--' + acc1);
            mapSAB.put(acc1.Subscription_Email__c, acc1);
            system.debug('--mapSAB--' + mapSAB);
        }
        }
        for (Account acc1: updatedAccountList) {
            system.debug('--acc1--' + acc1);
            mapUpdatedSAB.put(acc1.Subscription_Email__c, acc1);
            system.debug('--mapUpdatedSAB--' + mapUpdatedSAB);
        }

        if (!mapSAB.values().isEmpty()) {
            insert mapSAB.values();
            system.debug('--mapSAB.values()--' + mapSAB.values());

        }


        update mapAccount.values();

        //Populating Account lookup on partner lead object
        for(Partner_Lead__c pl :partnerLead){
            system.debug('--mapSAB acc id--'+mapSAB.get(pl.Email_Address__c));
            //system.debug('--mapAccount acc id--'+mapAccount.get(pl.Email_Address__c));
            if(mapSAB.get(pl.Email_Address__c)!=null){
                pl.Account__c=mapSAB.get(pl.Email_Address__c).id;               
                system.debug('--pl--'+pl);
            }
            else if(mapUpdatedSAB.get(pl.Email_Address__c)!=null){
                pl.Account__c=mapUpdatedSAB.get(pl.Email_Address__c).id;                
                system.debug('--pl--'+pl);
            }


         pllist.add(pl);   
         system.debug('--pllist!!!!--'+pllist);  
        }



        //List < Partner_Lead__c > pllist = new list < Partner_Lead__c > ();
        Integer cnt = 0;
        for (Partner_Lead__c pl: partnerLead1) {
            cnt++;
            plead = new Partner_Lead__c(id = pl.id);
            system.debug('--IF-Condition----' + checkDuplicateEmail.contains(pl.Email_Address__c) + ' && ' + !emailEntry.contains(pl.Email_Address__c));
            system.debug('--emailEntry-----' + emailEntry);
            if (!(emailEntry.contains(pl.Email_Address__c))) {
                plead.Updated__c = true;
                //updateSet.add(pl.Id);
                emailEntry.add(pl.Email_Address__c);
                system.debug('--IF-cnt-' + pl.Email_Address__c);
                /*
                if (mapSAB.get(pl.Email_Address__c) != null) {
                    plead.Account__c = mapSAB.get(pl.Email_Address__c).id;
                    system.debug('--plead--' + plead);
                }
                */
            } else {
                system.debug('--else-cnt-' + pl.Email_Address__c);
                plead.Conflict__c = true;
                // conflictSet.add(pl.Id);
            }
            partnerleadToBeUpdated.add(plead);
        }
        system.debug('--accountList--' + accountList);

        update partnerleadToBeUpdated;
        update pllist;
        system.debug('--pllist--' + pllist);
    }

}
```

Apex Test Class:

```
@isTest(Seealldata=true)
public class TestPartnerleadtoAccountscheduler {

        static testmethod void test1() 
        {
            Test.startTest();
             Partner_Lead__c P = new Partner_Lead__c();
                P.Business_Nature__c='IT';  
                P.Company_Name__c='PWC';
                P.Contact_Number__c='7894561230';
                P.Contact_Person__c='jacob';
                P.Date__c=System.today();
                P.Designation__c='Tester';
                P.Email_Address__c='grace1456@gmail.com';
                P.Package_Plan__c='1';
                P.CP_Name_Text__c='Anurag Avula';
                P.Updated__c=true;
                insert P;

                Profile pro = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='System Administrator'];
                /*
                User u=new User();
                u.Alias = 'standt';
                u.Email='newuser3@testorg.com'; 
                u.EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8';
                u.LastName='Testing';
                u.LanguageLocaleKey='en_US'; 
                u.LocaleSidKey='en_US';
                u.ProfileId = pro.Id; 
                u.TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles';
                u.UserName='newuser344@testorg.com';
                insert u;
                */
                Account A = new Account();
                A.LastName=P.Contact_Person__c;
                A.Subscription_Email__c='grace1456@gmail.com';
                A.Channel_Partner__c=true;
                A.Closure_Source__c='Organic';
                a.Business_Type__c='Product';
                a.Company_Name__c='Test';
                a.Phone='23456789';
                a.Designation__c='Salesforce Developer';
                a.AccountSource='Channel Partner';
                a.Package_Plan__c='CapTree';
                //a.CP_Name__c=u.id;
                a.Cp_Date__c=date.today();
                a.CP_Name_Text__c='Test';
                insert A;
            PartnerleadtoAccountscheduler scheUpdateAccount = new PartnerleadtoAccountscheduler();
            String sch ='0 57 * * * ?';    //This will run at 57th minute of any given hour. 
            System.schedule('Schedule to update Account Name', sch,scheUpdateAccount);  
            Test.stopTest();
        }

    static testmethod void TestPartnerleadtoAccountscheduler()
    {   
        Test.starttest();


        Partner_Lead__c P = new Partner_Lead__c();
        P.Business_Nature__c='IT';  
        P.Company_Name__c='PWC';
        P.Contact_Number__c='7894561230';
        P.Contact_Person__c='jacob';
        P.Date__c=System.today();
        P.Designation__c='Tester';
        P.Email_Address__c='grace123@gmail.com';
        P.Package_Plan__c='1';
        P.CP_Name_Text__c='Anurag Avula';
         P.Updated__c=true;
        insert P;

        Profile pro = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='System Administrator'];

        User u=new User();
        u.Alias = 'standt';
        u.Email='newuser1@testorg.com'; 
        u.EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8';
        u.LastName='Testing';
        u.LanguageLocaleKey='en_US'; 
        u.LocaleSidKey='en_US';
        u.ProfileId = pro.Id; 
        u.TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles';
        u.UserName='newuser1456@testorg.com';
        insert u;

        Account A = new Account();
        A.LastName=P.Contact_Person__c;
        A.Subscription_Email__c='grace123@gmail.com';
        A.Channel_Partner__c=true;
        A.Closure_Source__c='Organic';
        a.Business_Type__c='Product';
        a.Company_Name__c='Test';
        a.Phone='23456789';
        a.Designation__c='Salesforce Developer';
        a.AccountSource='Channel Partner';
        a.Package_Plan__c='CapTree';
        a.CP_Name__c=u.id;
        a.Cp_Date__c=date.today();
        a.CP_Name_Text__c='Test';
        insert A;

        Test.stoptest();
    }

    static testmethod void TestPartnerleadtoAccountscheduler1()
    {   
        Test.starttest();


        Partner_Lead__c P1 = new Partner_Lead__c();
        P1.Business_Nature__c='IT';  
        P1.Company_Name__c='PWC';
        P1.Contact_Number__c='7894561230';
        P1.Contact_Person__c='jacob';
        P1.Date__c=System.today();
        P1.Designation__c='Tester';
        P1.Email_Address__c='grace123456@gmail.com';
        P1.Package_Plan__c='1';
        P1.CP_Name_Text__c='Anurag Avula';
        P1.Updated__c=true;
        insert P1;

        Profile pro1 = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='System Administrator'];

        User u1=new User();
        u1.Alias = 'standt';
        u1.Email='newuser1@testorg.com'; 
        u1.EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8';
        u1.LastName='Testing';
        u1.LanguageLocaleKey='en_US'; 
        u1.LocaleSidKey='en_US';
        u1.ProfileId = pro1.Id; 
        u1.TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles';
        u1.UserName='newuser14564@testorg.com';
        insert u1;

        Account A1 = new Account();
        A1.LastName=P1.Contact_Person__c;
        A1.Subscription_Email__c='grace123456@gmail.com';
        A1.Channel_Partner__c=true;
        A1.Closure_Source__c='Organic';
        a1.Business_Type__c='Product';
        a1.Company_Name__c='Test';
        a1.Phone='23456789';
        a1.Designation__c='Salesforce Developer';
        a1.AccountSource='Channel Partner';
        a1.Package_Plan__c='CapTree';
        a1.CP_Name__c=u1.id;
        a1.Cp_Date__c=date.today();
        a1.CP_Name_Text__c='Test';
        insert A1;

        Test.stoptest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get the same error when testing in sandbox?

Comment: Can you point out the line 120 which throws the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would assume it's because you're using `@isTest(Seealldata=true)` on your test class and you have some `Partner_Lead__c` records in production that don't have a `Contact_Person__c` value.

Try doing this withouth the `(Seealldata=true)` on your test class, or make sure all `Partner_Lead__c` records in production have appropriate values.

Comment: Glad I could help.  Don't forget to mark answers that help you as the correct answer.

Comment: I've had this issue where I get the required field missing error on a specific field on a custom object. This field was deployed as a required field but was changes to not being required after a day. However, we're still getting this error once in a while on new records being inserted. I haven't been able to find out why this is happening. Please help if you have ideas as to what may be causing this. Thanks!

Comment: @Bahman.A, that sounds like a different problem to this question. Perhaps ask a new question so people can help